# Why does my reverse linked list function mutate the global variable linkedlist?

Tags: python, oop, linked-list, mutation

The following is my code:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.val) + " -> " + str(self.next)

def reverse_list(head: ListNode) -> ListNode:
    prev, curr  = None, head
    while curr:
        nxt = curr.next
        curr.next = prev
        prev = curr
        curr = nxt
    return prev

linked_list = ListNode(1, ListNode(2, ListNode(3)))
```

When printed out, linked_list is displayed as "1 -> 2 -> 3 -> None". However, after calling the function reverse_list once, and then printing linked_list again, it seems to be mutated and became 1 -> None. Could anyone explain the reasoning behind this? Example shown below:

```
print(linked_list)
# 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> None
print(reverse_list(linked_list))
# 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> None
print(linked_list)
# 1 -> None
```

Comment: Because you're modifying the list nodes in place. So the node that was originally first is now last.

Comment: `linked_list` still contains a reference to the node that was originally first, but now is last.

Comment: @Barmar Could you explain how my function was able to mutate the global variable? And is there a way to reverse a list without mutating the global variable? Thanks

Comment: It didn't mutate the global variable.

Comment: It mutated the object that the global variable references.

Comment: If you don't want to change the input list, you have to build a new list, node by node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the node instance that is *returned* is not the node instance that was passed to `reverse`.

It may help to visualise this. At the moment `reverse` is called, and is about to start the reversal, we have this state:

```
         curr
         head                                              prev 
          ↓                                                 ↓ 
        ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
        │ value: 1  │    │ value: 2  │    │ value: 3  │
        │ next: ───────> │ next: ───────> │ next: ───────> None
        └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘ 
          ↑
         linked_list (global)
```

Then when `reverse` has completed its loop, we have this:

```
curr     head                              prev
 ↓        ↓                                 ↓
        ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
        │ value: 1  │    │ value: 2  │    │ value: 3  │
None <────── :next  │ <────── :next  │ <─────── :next │
        └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘ 
          ↑
         linked_list (global)
```

`reverse` then *returns* the `prev` reference. It is clear that this referenced node is not the same one as the one that `linked_list` references.

So when `print(reverse_list(linked_list))` is called, the `__repr__` method will get the node with value 3 as argument, and will thus be able to print all nodes following the `next` chain.

However, when `print(linked_list)` is called, the `__repr__` method will get the node with value 1 as argument, and when the loop looks for the `next` attribute, it will find `None` -- which stops the printing. When you look at the above visualisation, you can see that if you start with `linked_list` as reference, the nodes with values 2 and 3 are unreachable. `linked_list` references the *tail* of the reversed list.

The "solution" is simple: you must *capture* the value returned by `reverse`, and you can re-assign it to the `linked_list` variable:

```
linked_list = reverse_list(linked_list)
```

Once that is executed, you get this visualisation:

```
        ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐    ┌───────────┐
        │ value: 1  │    │ value: 2  │    │ value: 3  │
None <────── :next  │ <────── :next  │ <─────── :next │
        └───────────┘    └───────────┘    └───────────┘ 
                                            ↑
                                           linked_list (global)
```

So change your main script to:

```
print(linked_list)
# 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> None
linked_list = reverse_list(linked_list)
print(linked_list)
# 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> None
```

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpful